# Can you put an online database to restoring mode?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that is online, I want to change it to restoring mode, usually I do this when I restore a DB `(WITH NORECOVERY)`.

Comment: Are you trying to ask if you can read the data within a database that is still in recovery mode? If that is your question, the answer is "no".

Comment: If you're asking how you change a database to recovery, you would need to restore a backup over it with the `WITH NORECOVERY` option. You can't put a database into recovery mode; it is specific to when restore a backup. If you want to stop access to it, set it to offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, basically it's used during Backup restoration (specially LOG Restores). i.e. during full backup restoration it must be set with `NO RECOVERY` in order to proceed with LOG backup chain.

However, in case if you want the ONLINE database to be set `RESTORING` state, perform [TAIL-LOG BACKUP (WITH NORECOVERY)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/tail-log-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), your database must be in FULL RECOVERY model for this to happen. following example for the reference:

```
Backup LOG YourDBName to disk = 'C:\SQL-Backups\YourDBName.trn' WITH NORECOVERY
```